Google Cloud CDN cache invalidation
I have 2 environments : prod and staging. I deploy static website files on cloud storage buckets. Separate resources have been created for each environment on google cloud:

subdomains: sub.example.com and sub-staging.example.com;

load balancers with backend buckets.


All resources are separated, created via terraform.
When I click the “Invalidate” button on the “Caching” tab of the “Load balancer details” page, the cache is invalidated for staging and prod load balancers. BUT when I click “Invalidate” button for prod load balancer, then cache invalidated only for prod load balancer.
“Invalidate” button
Same behavior when I run the command "gcloud compute url-maps invalidate-cdn-cache my-lb-staging --path "/*" --async".
I'm new to devops and google cloud, please help me understand what direction to take to figure out what the problem is.

Do you have Cloud CDN enabled on all the backendBuckets on the load balancer? Did you stipulate the FQDN values in your URL Map? Are the sub.example.com and sub-staging.example.com pointed to the froenent Anycast IP address for the load balancer?
